# Django: generic ListView, only show when in other model via ForeignKey

Tags: python, django

I have two models: Creator and Piece. Per default every user is a Creator. But only if the user uploads a Piece he actually created something. Hence I would like to show in the generic Creator ListView only those Creators that uploaded a Piece. How can I filter the generic ListView to only show Creators that are present in the model Piece via a ForeignKey?

**models.py**

```
class Creator(models.Model):
    ...
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

class Piece(models.Model):
    ...
    creator = models.ForeignKey('Creator', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    ...
```

**views.py**

```
class CreatorListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Creator
    paginate_by = 10
```

**creator_list.html**

```
{% block content %}
  <h1>Creators</h1>
  {% if creator_list %}
  <ul>
    {% for creator in creator_list %}
      <li>
        <a href="{{ creator.get_absolute_url }}">{{ creator }}</a>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  {% endif %}       
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You can override the queryset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the `queryset` such that it filters out `Creator`s with no *related* `Piece`:

```
class CreatorListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Creator
    queryset = Creator.objects.filter(piece__isnull=False).distinct()
    paginate_by = 10
```

Django will create a query that looks like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT creator.*
FROM creator
LEFT OUTER JOIN piece ON piece.creator_id = creator.id
WHERE piece.id IS NOT NULL
```

(It is possible that the Django ORM optimizes this to a `JOIN` instead of a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`).

So the `JOIN` will ensure that there is at least one related `Piece` object.